# javascript builtin function to convert string to number with strict semantics?

Tags: javascript

i'd like to convert a string to a number, if the string contains a valid number. to be exact: i want a function that gets a string and returns a number or NaN, depending on if the string contains and only contains a valid number, or not.

i tried both `parseInt` and `Number`, but they both are bad.

examples:

`parseInt('5haha') => 5  (i want NaN)
Number('') => 0 (i want NaN)`

of course i could create my own conversion tool with something like:

`const getNum = x => x ? Number(x) : NaN`

but i wonder, is there nothing builtin in javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#A_stricter_parse_function

Comment: so that is a "no there is no builtin", right?

Comment: Yep, there is no builtin strict string to number conversion function.